# GitHub API based app

Tags: javascript

I don't have formal training in coding, so I would like some input in my code. It is working really well, without any issues. I just wanted to see if I can somehow improve my code. I divided the major things into separate function.

[Here](http://www.devncode.com/git-api/) is a working demo.

```
(function($) {
    // Use _ to template the resultsTemplating details
    function resultsTemplating(data, inputValue) {
        var results = data,
            resultsTemplate = _.template($("#results-template").html()),
            resultingHtml = resultsTemplate({
                results : results,
                searchVal : inputValue,
                amount: results.length
            });

        // place the generated data into the html
        $("#results-container").html(resultingHtml);
    }
    // Use _ to template the overlay details
    function overlayTemplating(data, id) {
         // loop through JSON and match clicked element, then template   
         for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i].created == id) {
                var overlayTemplate = _.template($("#overlay-template").html()),
                    overlayHtml = overlayTemplate({
                        name : data[i].name,
                        username : data[i].username,
                        language: data[i].language,
                        url: data[i].url,
                        description: data[i].description
                    }); 


            }
        }
        // place the generated data into the html
        $("#overlay-container").html(overlayHtml);
    }
    // Grab Deatils of clicked node, and template it
    function repoDetails(data, id) {
        var container = $('#overlay-container');
        container.fadeIn('fast');

        overlayTemplating(data, id);

        // Closes the overlay
        container.find('.close').on('click', function() {
            container.fadeOut('fast');
            return false;
        });


    }
    // Scroll Back to the top of the page
    function backToTop() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'fast');
    }
    function searchGit() {
        //grab value of search field
        var search = $('#search').val();

        // Validates entered value
        if (search.length) {
            $(this).find('.error').hide();
            backToTop();

            //pull json data from url
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/' + search,
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: true,
                success: function(data) {

                    var results = data.repositories;

                    $('body').addClass('post');
                    $('#results-container').show();

                    // use the results to template the results html using _
                    resultsTemplating(results, search);

                    $('.viewDeatails').on('click', function(e) {
                        var id = $(this).attr('href');

                        // use the results to template the repo details html using _
                        repoDetails(results, id);

                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            });

            // Back to Home
            $('.logo').on('click', function() {
               $('body').removeClass('post'); 
               $('#results-container').hide();
            });
        } else {
            // Show error if search field is empty
            $(this).find('.error').fadeIn();
        }

        return false;
    }

   $(function() {
    if($('body').hasClass('js')) { 

        // ANIMATIONS
        $('#search').focus();

        $('.logo object').addClass('scaleInOut').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0,
                marginLeft: 0},
                400, function() {
                 $(this).next().addClass('fadeInDown').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        opacity : 1
                    });
                      $('form').addClass('fadeInUp').css({opacity : 1});
                      setTimeout(function() { $('.footer').fadeIn(); }, 400);
                 });
            });
        });  

        // Search Event
        $('#searchForm').on('submit', searchGit);
    }
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I expected the listed results to be links... it is boring to copy-paste the url in the browser tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small review, but your naming seems a bit repetitive.

This:

```
// Use _ to template the resultsTemplating details
function resultsTemplating(data, inputValue) {
    var results = data,
        resultsTemplate = _.template($("#results-template").html()),
        resultingHtml = resultsTemplate({
            results : results,
            searchVal : inputValue,
            amount: results.length
        });

    // place the generated data into the html
    $("#results-container").html(resultingHtml);
}
```

has `results` and `resulting` all over the place, I would go for something like this:

```
// Use _ to template the resultsTemplating details
function templateResults(results, searchValue) {
    var template = _.template($("#results-template").html()),
        html = resultsTemplate({
            results : results,
            searchVal : searchValue,
            amount: results.length
        });

    // place the generated data into the html
    $("#results-container").html(html);
}
```

I also removed the move from `data` to `results` to save a line and renamed `inputValue` to `searchValue`. I noticed that you have `inputValue` and `searchVal`, in my mind you want to be consistent and have `inputValue` and `searchValue` or `inputVal` and `searchVal`. I much prefer the fully spelled out name.

This bit is funny:

```
                overlayHtml = overlayTemplate({
                    name : data[i].name,
                    username : data[i].username,
                    language: data[i].language,
                    url: data[i].url,
                    description: data[i].description
                });
```

You are creating an object with the exact same properties which already exist in `data[i]`. Unless you have unwanted fields in `data[i]` that you really dont want in your template, you can simply

```
                overlayHtml = overlayTemplate(data[i]);
```

All in all, this is really great code for someone without formal training. I like the size of your functions, the level of commenting and how easy the code is to follow.